# What's a good alternative for input type date for dates before christ

Tags: html, forms, date, ipad

I'm making a historic timeline where people can add occurrences. Now I need an input where they can't choose any dates before -3000 (apparently a requirement) and today. Also I need the date in the correct format so I can insert it in the database, etc.

Input type=date doesn't really work because: 1) It doesn't work on firefox by default 2) It doesn't pick up the '-' sign 3) I'm afraid it might be a bit to small for iPads (the main device this site is written for)

Does anyone have any good alternatives? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe releated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896414/how-to-use-date-in-javascript-for-prehistoric-dates

Answer (score 0):

It seems jQuery Datepicker on type='text' inputs allows any year range:
[negative year example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGqkd.jpg)

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var currentYear = currentTime.getFullYear();
var initialYear = -3000-currentYear;

$("#date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', //change as you need
    changeMonth: true,
    yearRange: initialYear+':+0',
    changeYear: true
});
```