# Javascript handle big date (dates that has a year higher than the math max int)

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to do a javascript code that is able to handle huge dates. The date year might be higher than the max possible int.

I don't need hour, minutes, second and milliseconds from the current javascript Date object, just number of days.

I have been searching for libraries which might offer this possibility but I did not found any :(

I also looked at this answer: [How to use Date in Javascript for prehistoric dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896414/how-to-use-date-in-javascript-for-prehistoric-dates/34896556)

But I would like the solution to work with future dates also. And some past dates might be bigger than the big bang

I hope that someone can help me with this issue :)

Comment: Creating a structure to store such dates would be trivial, it's what you want to do with the dates that's more tricky.  So when you say handle huge date, could you be more specific in what ways you want to handle them.

Comment: I think you can take the same approach as the linked answer and use cycles of some multiple of 400 years (240,000 seems fine) plus a Date object to fill in the part cycle. So from the big bang to the current ECMAScript Date range, roughly 15 billion (1.5e10) years, is 62,500 cycles + Date.now(). It might even extend to the death of all stars in about 10 trillion years.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I would like just to store these dates and I don't need to do any computation, just the number of days since January first of year 0.

Comment: @Keith it is not that trivial to do such structure, because I have to handle leap years :(